# Long text content overlap footer fixed in pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page in HTML with long texts in sections, and these texts needs to go to another page because of his length, but the text overlap my footer fixed in all pages.

The page wasn't created to be seen in a browser, but was created to be printed. Because of that, the page is broken on browsers, but is fine on print.

I tried many things to not overlap my footer, but was unsuccessful. Can somebody help my with that?

This link show the page when I print: [Test Page](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9ys00mgde2hu8m/teste.pdf?dl=0)

Here's my HTML code, with CSS inline:

```css
.columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-fill: balance;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-fill: balance;
  column-count: 2;
  column-fill: auto;
  column-width: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
}

.footer {
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  right: 33px;
  width: 91%;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

@media screen {
  /* footer nao aparecer na tela*/
  footer.footer {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  /* footer aparecer na impresao*/
  footer.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    clear: both;
  }
  div.columns {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
}

@page {
  size: auto;
  /* auto is the initial value */
  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Prefeitura do Município de Francisco Morato</title>
  <!-- Meta -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!-- Global CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body style="margin: 8px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
  <div id="divPrincipal" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 25px; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;">
    <!-- div principal, margem do relatorio -->
    <img src="report/cabecalho.png" alt="cabecalho" style="width: 100%; padding-top: 20px" />
    <!-- cabecalho -->
    <div style="height: 25px; width: 100%;background-color: #505050 !important">
      <div style="display: block; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF !important">
        &nbsp;NR. 01 - Ano I
      </div>
      <div style="display: block; margin-left: 34.8%; font-size: 13.6px; margin-top: -16px; color: #FFFFFF !important">
        Segunda-feira, 18 de Setembro de 2017
      </div>
      <div style="display: block; margin-left: 75.2%; font-size: 9px; margin-top: -21px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF !important">
        Prefeitura Municipal de Francisco Morato <br/>
        <div style="font-weight: normal; margin-top: -3px; text-align: right; margin-right: 3.5%; color: #FFFFFF !important">
          www.franciscomorato.sp.gov.br
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 25px; width: 100%; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; background-color: #464646 !important;">
      <div style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF !important;">
        &nbsp;PODER EXECUTIVO
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="columns" style="padding: 0; margin-top: 20px;">
      <section>
        <div style="height: 16px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #B9B9B9 !important">
          SECRETARIA DE GOVERNO
        </div>
        <div style="height: 12px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px">
          TITULO DO DIARIO
        </div>
        <div style="height: 11px; text-align: center; font-size: 8px; font-style: italic; border-bottom: solid 1px #B9B9B9">
          Em 14 de Setembro de 2017
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-top: 4px solid #B9B9B9; margin-top: 1.5px"></div>
        <div style="text-align: justify; color: #000000; font-size: 7px;">
          in viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus et egestas lacus. Proin accumsan malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex fringilla gravida. In nec orci non diam ultrices dapibus. Aliquam
          elementum elit at tellus malesuada porttitor. Integer tempus tortor a vestibulum tincidunt. Nullam dictum laoreet enim, sed porta mi condimentum nec. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          Nulla sed nulla nec diam auctor elementum nec non erat. Cras id finibus nisl, non finibus lectus. Morbi ullamcorper quis leo sed aliquam. Nam ullamcorper dictum arcu, in viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus
          et egestas lacus. Proin accumsan malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex fringilla gravida. In nec orci non diam ultrices dapibus. Aliquam elementum elit at tellus malesuada porttitor. Integer tempus tortor
          a vestibulum tincidunt. Nullam dictum laoreet enim, sed porta mi condimentum nec. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex. Donec non est ex.
          <br/><br/> Sed nec posuere purus. Donec vulputate augue leo, in imperdiet odio rhoncus in. Curabitur sit amet nisi efficitur, hendrerit mi sed, tincidunt lorem. Morbi quis tincidunt arcu. Nulla laoreet diam a ipsum tristique, id finibus justo
          condimentum. Vestibulum convallis elit lobortis, imperdiet arcu eu, placerat purus. Nulla dignissim sem fermentum lorem aliquam commodo viverra nec sapien. Morbi consequat egestas interdum.
        </div>
        <div style="height: 7px; text-align: center; font-size: 7px; font-style: italic;">
          Francisco Morato, 14 de Setembro de 2017
        </div>
        <div style="height: 9px; text-align: center; font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold;">
          NOME DO SECRETARIA
        </div>
        <div style="height: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 7px;">
          Secretario de Governo
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="sessao">
        <div style="height: 16px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #B9B9B9 !important">
          SECRETARIA DE GOVERNO
        </div>
        <div style="height: 12px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px">
          TITULO DO DIARIO
        </div>
        <div style="height: 11px; text-align: center; font-size: 8px; font-style: italic; border-bottom: solid 1px #B9B9B9">
          Em 14 de Setembro de 2017
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-top: 4px solid #B9B9B9; margin-top: 1.5px"></div>
        <div style="text-align: justify; color: #000000; font-size: 7px;">
          <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 2px">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">17</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">22270000139</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">CLAUDIA PATRICIA ALMEIDA DE CARVALHO</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">201644411</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">63,33</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">18</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">22270000130</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">ADVANIR AP FERREIRA DA PAIX&Atilde;O BONIF&Aacute;CIO</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">128944493</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">55,00</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">21</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">22270000022</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">VIVIANE APARECIDA SILVA DOS ANJOS</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">304076831</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">52,50</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">22</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">22270000075</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">GIC&Eacute;LIA APARECIDA DE LIMA PENA DEMIRANDA</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">232360066</span></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:bottom"><span style="font-size:11px">63,33</span></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

        </div>
        <div style="height: 7px; text-align: center; font-size: 7px; font-style: italic;">
          Francisco Morato, 14 de Setembro de 2017
        </div>
        <div style="height: 9px; text-align: center; font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold;">
          NOME DO SECRETARIA
        </div>
        <div style="height: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 7px;">
          Secretario de Governo
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="sessao">
        <div style="height: 16px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #B9B9B9 !important">
          SECRETARIA DE GOVERNO
        </div>
        <div style="height: 12px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px">
          TITULO DO DIARIO
        </div>
        <div style="height: 11px; text-align: center; font-size: 8px; font-style: italic; border-bottom: solid 1px #B9B9B9">
          Em 14 de Setembro de 2017
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-top: 4px solid #B9B9B9; margin-top: 1.5px"></div>
        <div style="text-align: justify; color: #000000; font-size: 7px;">
          in viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus et egestas lacus. Proin accumsan malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex fringilla gravida. In nec orci non diamin viverra dui interdum
          non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus et egestas lacus. Proin accumsan malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex fringilla gravida. In nec orci non diamin viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis
          dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus et egestas lacus. Proin accumsan malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex fringilla gravida. In nec orci non diam ultrices dapibus. Aliquam elementum elit at tellus malesuada
          porttitor. Integer tempus tortor a vestibulum tincidunt. Nullam dictum laoreet enim, sed porta mi condimentum nec. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sed nulla nec diam auctor
          elementum nec non erat. Cras id finibus nisl, non finibus lectus. Morbi ullamcorper quis leo sed aliquam. Nam ullamcorper dictum arcu, in viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus et egestas lacus. Proin accumsan
          malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex fringilla gravida. In nec orci non diam ultrices dapibus. Aliquam elementum elit at tellus malesuada porttitor. Integer tempus tortor a vestibulum tincidunt. Nullam
          dictum laoreet enim, sed porta mi condimentum nec. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex. Donec non est ex.in viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus et egestas lacus.
          Proin accumsan malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex fringilla gravida. In nec orci non diamin viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus et egestas lacus. Proin accumsan
          malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex fringilla gravida. In nec orci non diamin viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus et egestas lacus. Proin accumsan malesuada dolor,
          sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex fringilla gravida. In nec orci non diam ultrices dapibus. Aliquam elementum elit at tellus malesuada porttitor. Integer tempus tortor a vestibulum tincidunt. Nullam dictum laoreet enim,
          sed porta mi condimentum nec. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sed nulla nec diam auctor elementum nec non erat. Cras id finibus nisl, non finibus lectus. Morbi ullamcorper
          quis leo sed aliquam. Nam ullamcorper dictum arcu, in viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus et egestas lacus. Proin accumsan malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque um tincidunt. Nullam
          dictum laoreet enim, sed porta mi condimentum nec. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex. Donec non est ex.in viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus et egestas lacus.
          Proin accumsan malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex fringilla gravida. In nec orci non diamin viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus et egestas lacus. Proin accumsan
          malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex frings. Morbi ullamcorper quis leo sed aliquam. Nam ullamcorper dictum arcu, in viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus et egestas
          lacus. Proin accumsan malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex fringilla gravida. In nec orci non diam ultrices dapibus. Aliquam elementum elit at tellus malesuada porttitor. Integer tempus tortor a vestibulum
          tincidunt. Nullam dictum laoreet enim, sed porta mi condimentum nec. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex. Donec non est ex.Aliquam elementum elit at tellus malesuada porttitor. Integer tempus tortor a
          vestibulum tincidunt. Nullam dictum laoreet enim, sed porta mi condimentum nec. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex. Donec non est ex.Aliquam elementum elit at tellus malesuada porttitor. Integer tempus
          tortor a vestibulum tincidunt. Nullam dictum laoreet enim, sed porta mi condimentum nec. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex. Donec non est ex.
          <br/><br/> Sed nec posuere purus. Donec vulputate augue leo, in imperdiet odio rhoncus in. Curabitur sit amet nisi efficitur, hendrerit mi sed, tincidunt lorem. Morbi quis tincidunt arcu. Nulla laoreet diam a ipsum tristique, id finibus justo
          condimentum. Vestibulum convallis elit lobortis, imperdiet arcu eu, placerat purus. Nulla dignissim sem fermentum lorem aliquam commodo viverra nec sapien. Morbi consequat egestas interdum.
        </div>
        <div style="height: 7px; text-align: center; font-size: 7px; font-style: italic;">
          Francisco Morato, 14 de Setembro de 2017
        </div>
        <div style="height: 9px; text-align: center; font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold;">
          NOME DO SECRETARIA
        </div>
        <div style="height: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 7px;">
          Secretario de Governo
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="sessao">
        <div style="height: 16px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #B9B9B9 !important">
          SECRETARIA DE GOVERNO
        </div>
        <div style="height: 12px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px">
          TITULO DO DIARIO
        </div>
        <div style="height: 11px; text-align: center; font-size: 8px; font-style: italic; border-bottom: solid 1px #B9B9B9">
          Em 14 de Setembro de 2017
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-top: 4px solid #B9B9B9; margin-top: 1.5px"></div>
        <div style="text-align: justify; color: #000000; font-size: 7px;">
          in viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus et egestas lacus. Proin accumsan malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex fringilla gravida. In nec orci non diam ultrices dapibus. Aliquam
          elementum elit at tellus malesuada porttitor. Integer tempus tortor a vestibulum tincidunt. Nullam dictum laoreet enim, sed porta mi condimentum
          <br/><br/> Sed nec posuere purus. Donec vulputate augue leo, in imperdiet odio rhoncus in. Curabitur sit amet nisi efficitur, hendrerit mi sed, tincidunt lorem. Morbi quis tincidunt arcu. Nulla laoreet diam a ipsum tristique, id finibus justo
          condimentum. Vestibulum convallis elit lobortis, imperdiet arcu eu, placerat purus. Nulla dignissim sem fermentum lorem aliquam commodo viverra nec sapien. Morbi consequat egestas interdum.
        </div>
        <div style="height: 7px; text-align: center; font-size: 7px; font-style: italic;">
          Francisco Morato, 14 de Setembro de 2017
        </div>
        <div style="height: 9px; text-align: center; font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold;">
          NOME DO SECRETARIA
        </div>
        <div style="height: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 7px;">
          Secretario de Governo
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="sessao">
        <div style="height: 16px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #B9B9B9 !important">
          SECRETARIA DE GOVERNO
        </div>
        <div style="height: 12px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px">
          TITULO DO DIARIO
        </div>
        <div style="height: 11px; text-align: center; font-size: 8px; font-style: italic; border-bottom: solid 1px #B9B9B9">
          Em 14 de Setembro de 2017
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-top: 4px solid #B9B9B9; margin-top: 1.5px"></div>
        <div style="text-align: justify; color: #000000; font-size: 7px;">
          in viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus et egestas lacus. Proin accumsan malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex fringilla gravida. In nec orci non diam ultrices dapibus. Aliquam
          elementum elit at tellus malesuada porttitor. Integer tempus tortor a vestibulum tincidunt. Nullam dictum laoreet enim, sed porta mi condimentum nec. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          Nulla sed nulla nec diam auctor elementum nec non erat. Cras id finibus nisl, non finibus lectus. Morbi ullamcorper quis leo sed aliquam. Nam ullamcorper dictum arcu, in viverra dui interdum non. Duis venenatis dignissim erat vitae auctor. Vivamus
          et egestas lacus. Proin accumsan malesuada dolor, sed porta nibh venenatis vel. Pellentesque eget neque ut ex fringilla gravida. In nec orci non diam ultrices dapibus. Aliquam elementum elit at tellus malesuada porttitor. Integer tempus tortor
          a vestibulum tincidunt. Nullam dictum laoreet enim, sed porta mi condimentum nec. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex. Suspendisse potenti. Donec non est ex. Donec non est ex.
          <br/><br/> Sed nec posuere purus. Donec vulputate augue leo, in imperdiet odio rhoncus in. Curabitur sit amet nisi efficitur, hendrerit mi sed, tincidunt lorem. Morbi quis tincidunt arcu. Nulla laoreet diam a ipsum tristique, id finibus justo
          condimentum. Vestibulum convallis elit lobortis, imperdiet arcu eu, placerat purus. Nulla dignissim sem fermentum lorem aliquam commodo viverra nec sapien. Morbi consequat egestas interdum.
        </div>
        <div style="height: 7px; text-align: center; font-size: 7px; font-style: italic;">
          Francisco Morato, 14 de Setembro de 2017
        </div>
        <div style="height: 9px; text-align: center; font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold;">
          NOME DO SECRETARIA
        </div>
        <div style="height: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 7px;">
          Secretario de Governo
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="sessao">
        <div style="height: 16px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #B9B9B9 !important">
          SECRETARIA DE GOVERNOdddd
        </div>
        <div style="height: 12px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px">
          TITULO DO DIARIO
        </div>
        <div style="height: 11px; text-align: center; font-size: 8px; font-style: italic; border-bottom: solid 1px #B9B9B9">
          Em 14 de Setembro de 2017
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-top: 4px solid #B9B9B9; margin-top: 1.5px"></div>
        <div style="text-align: justify; color: #000000; font-size: 7px;">
          Sed nec posuere purus. Donec vulputate augue leo, in imperdiet odio rhoncus in. Curabitur sit amet nisi efficitur, hendrerit mi sed, tincidunt lorem. Morbi quis tincidunt arcu. Nulla laoreet diam a ipsum tristique, id finibus justo condimentum. Vestibulum
          convallis elit lobortis, imperdiet arcu eu, placerat purus. Nulla dignissim sem fermentum lorem aliquam commodo viverra nec sapien. Morbi consequat egestas interdum.Sed nec posuere purus. Donec vulputate augue leo, in imperdiet odio rhoncus
          in. Curabitur sit amet nisi efficitur, hendrerit mi sed, tincidunt lorem. Morbi quis tincidunt arcu. Nulla laoreet diam a ipsum tristique, id finibus justo condimentum. Vestibulum convallis elit lobortis, imperdiet arcu eu, placerat purus. Nulla
          dignissim sem fermentum lorem aliquam commodo viverra nec sapien. Morbi consequat egestas interdum.
          <br/> Sed nec posuere purus. Donec vulputate augue leo, in imperdiet odio rhoncus in. Curabitur sit amet nisi efficitur, hendrerit mi sed, tincidunt lorem. Morbi quis tincidunt arcu. Nulla laoreet diam a ipsum tristique, id finibus justo condimentum.
          Vestibulum convallis elit lobortis, imperdiet arcu eu, placerat purus. Nulla dignissim sem fermentum lorem aliquam commodo viverra nec sapien. Morbi consequat egestas interdum.
        </div>
        <div style="height: 7px; text-align: center; font-size: 7px; font-style: italic;">
          Francisco Morato, 15 de Setembro de 2017
        </div>
        <div style="height: 9px; text-align: center; font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold;">
          NOME DO SECRETARIA
        </div>
        <div style="height: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 7px;">
          Secretario de Governo
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="sessao">
        <div style="height: 16px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #B9B9B9 !important">
          SECRETARIA DE GOVERNOdddd
        </div>
        <div style="height: 12px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px">
          TITULO DO DIARIO
        </div>
        <div style="height: 11px; text-align: center; font-size: 8px; font-style: italic; border-bottom: solid 1px #B9B9B9">
          Em 14 de Setembro de 2017
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-top: 4px solid #B9B9B9; margin-top: 1.5px"></div>
        <div style="text-align: justify; color: #000000; font-size: 7px;">
          Sed nec posuere purus. Donec vulputate augue leo, in imperdiet odio rhoncus in. Curabitur sit amet nisi efficitur, hendrerit mi sed, tincidunt lorem. Morbi quis tincidunt arcu. Nulla laoreet diam a ipsum tristique, id finibus justo condimentum. Vestibulum
          convallis elit lobortis, imperdiet arcu eu, placerat purus. Nulla dignissim sem fermentum lorem aliquam commodo viverra nec sapien. Morbi consequat egestas interdum.Sed nec posuere purus. Donec vulputate augue leo, in imperdiet odio rhoncus
          in. Curabitur sit amet nisi efficitur, hendrerit mi sed, tincidunt lorem. Morbi quis tincidunt arcu. Nulla laoreet diam a ipsum tristique, id finibus justo condimentum. Vestibulum convallis elit lobortis, imperdiet arcu eu, placerat purus. Nulla
          dignissim sem fermentum lorem aliquam commodo viverra nec sapien. Morbi consequat egestas interdum.
          <br/> Sed nec posuere purus. Donec vulputate augue leo, in imperdiet odio rhoncus in. Curabitur sit amet nisi efficitur, hendrerit mi sed, tincidunt lorem. Morbi quis tincidunt arcu. Nulla laoreet diam a ipsum tristique, id finibus justo condimentum.
          Vestibulum convallis elit lobortis, imperdiet arcu eu, placerat purus. Nulla dignissim sem fermentum lorem aliquam commodo viverra nec sapien. Morbi consequat egestas interdum.
        </div>
        <div style="height: 7px; text-align: center; font-size: 7px; font-style: italic;">
          Francisco Morato, 15 de Setembro de 2017
        </div>
        <div style="height: 9px; text-align: center; font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold;">
          NOME DO SECRETARIA
        </div>
        <div style="height: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 7px;">
          Secretario de Governo
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <img id="seloAssinado" src="report/selo.png" width="97" height="97" style="margin-top: 4px;" />
  </footer>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    //print();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you could recreate from zero without css inline, sorry it's hard to help.

Comment: Why not just move the @ media screen portion of the footer.footer to the main css and display: block in the @ media printer section?